# Save point never created error

Tags: sql, windows-7, oracle11g, savepoints

I'm trying to create a savepoint in Oracle 11g.

```
ALTER TABLE ORDERS
DISABLE CONSTRAINT ORDERS_C_ID_FK;

DELETE FROM CUSTOMER;

SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER;

ROLLBACK;

SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER;

SAVEPOINT SAVEPOINT1;

ALTER TABLE ORDERS
DISABLE CONSTRAINT ORDERS_OS_ID_FK;

ALTER TABLE ORDER_LINE
DISABLE CONSTRAINT ORDER_LINE_O_ID_FK;

TRUNCATE TABLE CUSTOMER;
TRUNCATE TABLE ORDER_SOURCE;
TRUNCATE TABLE ORDERS;
DELETE FROM ORDERS;

ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT1;
```

But I keep getting this error from SQL Developer

> ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT1 Error report: SQL Error: ORA-01086: savepoint
>   'SAVEPOINT1' never established in this session or is invalid
>   01086. 00000 -  "savepoint '%s' never established"
>   *Cause:    Trying to roll back to a save point that was never established.
>   *Action:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DDL` statements-- `ALTER TABLE` and `TRUNCATE TABLE` in this case-- issue implicit commits before and after they are executed.  The transaction that the savepoint was created in was ended before the first `ALTER TABLE` statement was executed.  Since you can only rollback to a savepoint defined in the current transaction, you cannot rollback to the savepoint after issuing `DDL` statements.